# How to animate an element on an inner change with Svelte?

Tags: svelte

Transitions in Svelte only apply to elements entering or exiting the DOM.

For example this would apply the fade when the `div` is initially added to the DOM:

```
<div in:fade>{message}</div>
```

How can we add a transition instead when `message` changes?

Since Svelte cannot have keys on single elements, the only solution I've found is to use a single element array to trigger a new element in the DOM whenever the array changes which doesn't seem ideal:

```
<script>
let messages = ['hello world'];

function updateMessages (message) {
    messages = [message];
}
</script>

{#each messages as message (message)}
    <div in:fade>{message}</div>
{/each}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As of Svelte 3.28, there is a {#key} that implements that functionality - see https://svelte.dev/docs#key

As an example this will cause the  to run its transition whenever value changes.

```
{#key value}
    <div transition:fade>{value}</div>
{/key}
```

Comment: Please add an example and I will mark your answer as valid!

Comment: When I try this, it keeps two divs around while the transition is happening, one fades in and one fades out.  After the transition is complete, it goes back to one div.  Solved this by changing transition:fade to in:fade

Comment: Here is an example: https://svelte.dev/repl/bc15ae91a2ba40c4a8d4f4ce026c8387?version=3.48.0

Comment: @killdash9 Apologies for the necro, but the duplication seems to be happening because svelte just superimposes the two values while transitioning from one to the other. As can be seen in the example, positioning the element `absolute`-ly solves the issue. ‍♂️

Answer (score 7):

Your `#each` hack is indeed the recommended approach, currently (we may add something like a `key` directive in future, but no promises) — I'd just make one alteration, which is to do `#each [x] as x` rather than maintaining an array separately:

```html
<script>
let message = 'hello world';

function updateMessages (new_message) {
    message = new_message;
}
</script>

{#each [message] as message (message)}
    <div in:fade>{message}</div>
{/each}
```

Comment: Thanks for the array idea Rich, I didn't expect that work! Hopefully a `key` lands on Svelte someday.